# Querying nested fields on elastic doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data that looks like this:

```
{
  "F": {},
  "H": {},
  "M": "10000000",
  "N": {},
  "D": {
    "C": [
      {
        "A": "555",
        "B": ""
      },
      {
        "A": "600",
        "B": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to query elastic so I only get those results which have value A = 600.

I tried many different queries to get what I want but let's focus on most simple one now:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "D.C",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "D.C.A": "600"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work and I just get a response Not a valid query, with no errors.

Comment: Can you show the mapping of `D` and `C`?